# AVCapturePhotoSettings error in ios 10?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcapturephotooutput

My application have use camera then compress image JPEG, with ios version < 10 , I have use AVCaptureStillImageOutput but ios version >= 10 I use AVCapturePhotoOutput error.I have setting code:`

```
self.photoOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
        AVCapturePhotoSettings *photoSettings =
            [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG}];

    [self.photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:photoSettings delegate:self];
    [self.session addOutput:self.photoOutput];`
```

I have problems when run app, app crash with error:

```
[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] No active and enabled video connection
```

Does anybody know how to use this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `[self.session addOutput:];` before `[self.photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:];`

Try:

```
self.photoOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
        AVCapturePhotoSettings *photoSettings =
            [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
[self.photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:photoSettings delegate:self];
[self.session addOutput:self.photoOutput];
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequence to make the connection is important.

```
self.photoOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
AVCapturePhotoSettings *photoSettings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
if ([self.session canAddOutput: self.photoOutput ]){
     [self.session addOutput: self.photoOutput]
}
[self.photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:photoSettings delegate:self];
```